# How to combine two character vectors in r to form a new vector?

Tags: r

I have two vectors as shown below.

```
a<-c("a","b","c","d")
b<-"constant"
```

Now I need to combine above two vectors and the final output should be in the form as I showed below.

```
list(a="constant",b="constant",c="constant",d="constant")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can repeat `b`, `length(a)` times gives them names with `setNames` and convert it into list.

```
as.list(setNames(rep(b, length(a)), a))

#$a
#[1] "constant"

#$b
#[1] "constant"

#$c
#[1] "constant"

#$d
#[1] "constant"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
l <- as.list(rep(b, length(a)))
names(l) <- a
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an other way that might be simpler:

```
l <- list()
l[a] <- b
```